# Trying to disallow users from accessing my image folders using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to disallow other users from accessing my image(s) through google images or from direct accessing them (eg. mysite.com/img/protected_image.jpg), so, I've looked at some htaccess script I can use.

here's the snippet I found:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}!^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}!^http://(www\.)?mysite.com(/)?.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif¦jpg¦png)$ - [F]
```

and here's how I append it on my existing **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}!^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}!^http://(www\.)?mysite.com(/)?.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif¦jpg¦png)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```

I'm running on Wordpress and it comes with it's own htaccess configuration, just so you know why I append it. I changed "mysite" to my actual domain name.

When I deployed the htaccess file to my server, I got an Internal Server Error. Obviously, I've implemented it the wrong way, my knowledge on .htaccess is very limited and I'm not able to trace what's causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order of your rules. Otherwise `index.php` is your `catch all` front controller that changes request URI and then last image blocking rule doesn't kick -in.

Try this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ - [F,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```